# Dynamically add and remove controls, using uwp windows 10 visual studio 2015

Tags: dynamic, visual-studio-2015, controls, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

Edit:23-10;15:37h
Lets make one very big story very small. I've found out a lot!

[first impressing of possibible layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3UVw.jpg)

I want a program, were I can place/replace/rotate/adjust/remove fences in a field.

At this point I drag the fences from the listview into the canvas. But now I have a problem. I can't give those a name. I can't find a way to interact.

And seeing that I have come this far. Perhaps it's best to consider a save/load option. I expect some sort of csv of xml file could be used.

---

**xaml.cs**

```
 byte Selectie = 0;



    private void parcours_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        var pointer = e.GetPosition(parcours);

        //following lines are used to create an object.
        if (Selectie !=0)
        {
            Image enkel = new Image();


            enkel.Width = 70;
            enkel.Height = 70;
            if (Selectie == 1)
            {
                enkel.Source = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/hindernissen_01.png"));
            }
            if (Selectie == 2)
            {
                enkel.Source = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/hindernissen_02.png"));
            }
            if (Selectie == 3)
            {
                enkel.Source = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/hindernissen_03.png"));
            }
            enkel.CanDrag = true;

            parcours.Children.Add(enkel);
            Canvas.SetTop(enkel, pointer.Y - 35);
            Canvas.SetLeft(enkel, pointer.X - 35);

        }
        if (Selectie == 0)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(enkel, pointer.Y - 35);
            Canvas.SetLeft(enkel, pointer.X - 35);
        }



        Selectie = 0;
    }


    private void parcours_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {


        e.AcceptedOperation = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackageOperation.Move;//you must accept accept a drop. prevents it from dropping anywere.
    }

    private void tripple_DragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        Selectie = 3;
    }

    private void dubbel_DragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        Selectie = 2;
    }

    private void enkel_DragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        Selectie = 1;
    }
```

**mainpage**

```
    <Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Header1" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Height="59" Margin="118,0,0,0" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Parcourshulp" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="840" 
                   Foreground="Black" FontSize="48" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   />

        <Rectangle Fill="Red" 
                   Height="18" 
                   Margin="1,64,0,0" 
                   Stroke="Black" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 

                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   />

        <Canvas x:Name="parcours" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 

                Height="306" 
                Margin="33,176,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="745" 
                Background="#FFECE2E2" 
                AllowDrop="True" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Drop="parcours_Drop" DragOver="parcours_DragOver">
            <Image x:Name="enkel_Copy2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" RenderTransformOrigin="0.09,-0.015" Source="Assets/hindernissen_01.png" CanDrag="True" Canvas.Left="456" Canvas.Top="195" />

        </Canvas>

        <ListView x:Name="listView" Background="#FFECE2E2"  Height="306" Margin="827,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="107" RenderTransformOrigin="0.518,0.532">
            <Image x:Name="enkel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" RenderTransformOrigin="0.09,-0.015" Source="Assets/hindernissen_01.png" CanDrag="True" DragStarting="enkel_DragStarting">

            </Image>
            <Image x:Name="dubbel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" RenderTransformOrigin="0.09,-0.015" Source="Assets/hindernissen_02.png" CanDrag="True" DragStarting="dubbel_DragStarting"/>
            <Image x:Name="tripple" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" RenderTransformOrigin="0.09,-0.015" Source="Assets/hindernissen_03.png" CanDrag="True" DragStarting="tripple_DragStarting"/>


        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: In short, you want to drag an item from ListView to Canvas and have ability to rotate this item on Canvas, give a name or Id to this item so can it be removed from canvas?

Comment: Yes,  though considering mouse and keyboard users. Also, I want to drag an instance of the object in the listview

Comment: You make it sound so simple Grace ;-). I've edited my post. Learn't a lot in the past 2 days. But once placed an image on the canvas I'm unable to move it again.

Comment: Due to personal issue, I'm now not able to write a code sample for you, but I can give some suggestions here. Once the item is draged from `ListView` and placed on the canvas, you can detect the manipulations of each item by registering the same manipulation events handler for all the items.

Comment: So far I havn't found the answer I was Looking for. I have found a way to manipulate the created items using the xy manipulation. But considering I want to use external sensor data to display time and faults and points. Maybe an universal app with c# was a wrong way to start?